# Flutter A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to get the five questions which i have define in the datascore. It only shows me one of them and a error with (A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget). Help i dont know how to fix this.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvakY.png)

Code of the Datascore File:

```
class DataSource{
  static String quote = "Bitte halten Sie die drei AHA-Formel im Alltag ein, um die Pandemie einzudämmen";

  static List questionAnswers = [
    {
      "question" : "Was ist über den Erreger und die Krankheit bekannt?",
      "answer" : 
      "Informationen zu SARS-CoV-2 (offizielle Bezeichnung des neuartigen Coronavirus) und COVID-19 (offizielle Bezeichnung der Erkrankung durch das neuartige Coronavirus) sind im Steckbrief zu COVID-19 zusammengefasst. Das Dokument wird fortlaufend aktualisiert.Informationen zu den besorgniserregenden Virusvarianten (VOC) sind auch auf der dazugehörigen Übersichtseite unter www.rki.de/covid-19-varianten zu finden Stand: 02.03.2021",
    },
    {
      "question" : "Was ist der Unterschied zwischen SARS und SARS-CoV-2?",
      "asnwer" :
      "Das Akronym SARS steht für Schweres Akutes Atemwegssyndrom. Das Syndrom wurde erstmals im November 2002 entdeckt. Der SARS-Erreger stammt aus derselben Virusfamilie wie das Coronavirus. Das Coronavirus ähnelt dem SARS-Virus daher sehr. Aufgrund dieser engen Verwandtschaft wird das Virus als SARS-CoV-2 bezeichnet. Ein wesentlicher Unterschied zwischen den Viren ist, dass bei SARS die Symptome häufig auftreten, bevor das Virus weiter übertragen werden kann. So lassen sich Infektionsketten leichter unterbrechen. Im Gegensatz dazu kann das Coronavirus noch vor den ersten Symptomen übertragen werden. In machen Fällen treten gar keine Symptome auf.",
    },
    {
      "question": "Was bedeutet die Mutation des Coronavirus für uns und was weiß man über sie?",
      "answer" : 
      "Seit Ende 2020 wird aus Großbritannien, Südafrika und Brasilien über die zunehmende Verbreitung einer neu aufgetretenen Virusvariante berichtet. Diese Varianten weisen eine erhöhte Übertragbarkeit und höhere Reproduktionsanzahl auf. Um einen besseren Überblick über Virusmutationen zu bekommen, fördert die Bundesregierung die bundesweite Sequenzierung der Viren. Virologische Basisdaten und Virusvarianten zu SARS-CoV-2 stellt das RKI hier zur Verfügung. Angesichts der neu aufgetretenen Mutationen ist es umso wichtiger, die bekannte AHA-Formel konsequent zu beachten, um generell eine Übertragung von SARS-CoV-2 zu verhindern und die Ausbreitung der neuen, möglicherweise noch stärker ansteckenden Variante einzudämmen.",
    },
    {
      "question": "Was sind die Symptome von COVID-19?",
      "answer": 
      "Die häufigsten Symptome sind Fieber über 38°C, Husten, Schnupfen, Kopf- und Gliederschmerzen, Abgeschlagenheit sowie Kratzen im Hals. Bei einigen Personen kommt es zu einem vorübergehenden Verlust des Geruchs- und Geschmackssinns, dessen Ursache derzeit erforscht wird. Einige Menschen können eine Lungenentzündung mit Kurzatmigkeit und Luftnot bekommen. Sie sollten Ihre Ärztin oder Ihren Arzt verständigen, wenn Sie das Gefühl haben, schwerer Luft zu bekommen als sonst. Die meisten COVID-19-Verläufe sind allerdings eher mild, viele davon verlaufen symptomlos. Dies hat zur Folge, dass Menschen, die sich gesund fühlen, andere Menschen infizieren können, ohne es zu wissen. Achten Sie daher stets auf die allgemein geltenden Maßnahmen, die in der AHA-Formel zusammengefasst sind: Abstand halten (Mindestabstand 1,5 Meter), Hygieneregeln beachten (Husten und Niesen in die Armbeuge oder ein Papiertaschentuch, Händewaschen), im Alltag eine Maske tragen (wenn es eng wird oder in vollen, geschlossenen Räumen).",
    },
      { 
      "question" : "Was ist über den Erreger und die Krankheit bekannt?",
      "answer" : 
      "Informationen zu SARS-CoV-2 (offizielle Bezeichnung des neuartigen Coronavirus) und COVID-19 (offizielle Bezeichnung der Erkrankung durch das neuartige Coronavirus) sind im Steckbrief zu COVID-19 zusammengefasst. Das Dokument wird fortlaufend aktualisiert.Informationen zu den besorgniserregenden Virusvarianten (VOC) sind auch auf der dazugehörigen Übersichtseite unter www.rki.de/covid-19-varianten zu finden Stand: 02.03.2021",

       },




  ];
}
```

Comment: you wrote badly 'answer' in the second line of your Datascore file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because one `answer` is null. In your case you have a type on your second item in your list. It has the property `asnwer` instead of `answer` which means your second item will return `answer = null`.

Comment: You are welcome. Consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Danke nochmal auf Deutsch :))